# How to get system back button in mvvm with side menu in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have used mvvm using Kotlin. I have login to dashboard with side menu. I have attached navigation with fragments.I need to add logoout option from fragment dashboard.In fragments it did not get onbackpress. I have tried bellow code in welcome activity.

```
override fun onBackPressed() {

    val fragments: List<Fragment> =
        supportFragmentManager.fragments
    if (fragments != null) {
        for (f in fragments) {               
                if (f is Welcome_Dash_Board) {
                    //Log out action
                }               
        }
    }
}
```

**Welcome_Dash_Board** is the dashboard Fragment. Only this fragment will called logout options when system back button press. But Welcome_Dash_Board is not found.
How to used backpress on specific fragment programatically using mvvm?

Comment: check  your activity on backpressed method

Comment: @Avinash in activity on backpresssed method shows all other fragments too. I want show only specific fragments.

Comment: @Avinash above code tried on backpress on welcome activity

Comment: In on backpress use    val fragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.container)

Comment: @Avinash same as previous

Comment: check fragment, which fragment found?

Comment: @Avinash it is null

Comment: add your fragment first in activity and add to back stack also